# Using git submodules in jelastic

Tags: git, jelastic

I am using git submodule in project.
When I try to update project, I see 'java.io.IOException: Timeout while waiting for data.'.

In git log there are

```
04/28/14. 4:36:38.315904463spawn /usr/bin/git submodule update --init --recursive
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/webroot/ROOT-476/protected/modules/present/models/.git/
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (131.103.20.167)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

What I need to do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try a `ssh -Tvvv git@bitbucket.org` in command line, and answer `yes` to the question asked about the authenticity of host '`bitbucket.org`'

Then you can update your project again.

It is hanging because it is waiting on stdin for an entry.

since it is Jelastic cloud, you would need to request ssh access (See [Jelastic SSH Access](http://kb.layershift.com/jelastic-ssh-access)), for instance:

```
ssh 4856@gate.j.layershift.co.uk -p 3022
```

In that session, you will be able to update the host fingerprints file in order to record bitbucket in it.

Comment: I know it, but there are no command line in jelastic apache node!

Comment: @verybadbug you don't have access to a command line on the machine where that process run?

Comment: this is cloud. I can add terminal node, but its virtualy separated from apache node (where repo placed). Configuring (including update git repo) is made through web interface.

Comment: @verybadbug so you can get the console as in http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-master-aws-ec2-cloud-automation-with-puppet/# ? (`aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id xxx`)

Comment: Project placed not on AWS... it placed on Jelastic cloud.

Comment: @verybadbug ok, and can you open an ssh session? (as in http://kb.layershift.com/jelastic-ssh-access: `ssh 4856@gate.j.layershift.co.uk -p 3022`)

Comment: I can't open ssh. But this is good idea. I'll ask my provider to give me ssh access to apache node. After provider do that you wrote there is another problem. It needs to generate keys to work with git repo through ssh.

Comment: If I had ssh access, I would have done it myself more faster. Thanks for help!

Comment: @verybadbug Ok. I have included the "JElastic ssh access" in the answer for more visibility.